# Mocked HttpServletRequest not returning expected method value

Tags: http, junit, mockito

I have a filter in Spring that does some logic based on Method type of the incoming request. Below is the filter code:

```
public class TestFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        if (HttpMethod.GET.equals(httpRequest.getMethod())) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, httpResponse);
    }
}
```

In the above code, I am trying to set some header in my response called `GETHEADER` whenever the request method is `GET` whereas it doesn't happen in `POST`.

And I am trying to test it using the below testcase code:

```
@Mock
HttpServletResponse response;

@Mock
HttpServletRequest request;

@Mock
FilterChain chain;

@Autowired
TestFilter testFilter;

@Test
public void testGetRequest() throws Exception {
    when(request.getMethod()).thenReturn(HttpMethod.GET.toString());
    testFilter.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    Assert.assertNotNull(response.getHeader("GETHEADER"));
}
```

In my code coverage, I can only see the else part being executed but never the if part. Is it not returning the value I try to supply or is there some problem with how I am returning?

**UPDATE**: Tried these as below:

code: `if (HttpMethod.GET.toString().equals(httpRequest.getMethod()))`

testcase: `when(request.getMethod()).thenReturn(HttpMethod.GET.toString())`

also

code: `if ("GET".toString().equals(httpRequest.getMethod()))`

testcase: `when(request.getMethod()).thenReturn("GET")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enum value is never equal to a String. `HttpMethod.GET` is an enum value. `httpRequest.getMethod()` is a String.

Comment: Yes I forgot to update that I have tried those. See my updated question.

Comment: Retry. That should work fine. If you want more help, post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem (i.e. the complete (but minimal) code of the filter, and the complete (but minimal) code of the test. But if the header is only set in the if block, and your test passes, then obviously the if block is executed. So the problem can be how you measure or visualize the code coverage.

Comment: Actually the test fails. I changed my assert to `assertNull` just so that it passes to visualize the problem in my code. Anyways, will retry. I think using `toString()` is better than the direct comparison. Hope that is correct.

Comment: okay it works. I had to do a clean build for the code to compile properly. My bad.